# Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Slow wifi connection on specific wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, connection

I have my laptop (dual boot Windows/Ubuntu). When I'm using the Ubuntu part at my home, the Wifi is really **slow** at a point I can't do simple google requests.

I can use `ping` and it works well, and when I'm sharing connection with my phone or use another network (school, work or different house) it works perfectly fine.

I already tried several solutions but none of them worked :

- Disabling `802.11n`
- Editing `nsswitch.conf`
- Disable IPv6 support
- Adding REGDOMAIN
- etc...

if anyone have an idea on why it doesn't work on specific networks I would be really delightful !